# MulterError: Unexpected field error while uploading image from React js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

All the answers related this error is directing towards checking the name `upload.single("image")` and the name attribute of the file input in client side, which is in my case same as "image" as multer. But still it is giving the error.

Following is the node js code:

```
const Imagestorage = multer.memoryStorage()
 const upload = multer({ storage: Imagestorage })

app.post("/newpost", upload.single("image"), async(req, res) => {

     console.log(req.body);
     console.log(req.file);

let data={}
   // convert base64 image data to string using datauri/parser, upload to cloudinary and send response

  const extName = path.extname(req.file.originalname).toString();
  const file64 = parser.format(extName, req.file.buffer);
  const filename=file64.content

  cloudinary.uploader.upload(filename, async(error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send("error in uploading file to cloudinary"+error);
    } else {
      // result.secure_url is the URL of the uploaded file on Cloudinary
      console.log(result.secure_url);

        let Imageurl=await result.secure_url
          data={
             name: req.body.name,
             location:req.body.location,
             likes:req.body.likes,
             description:req.body.description,
              image:Imageurl
            }
             console.log(data)
             let postedData=await postsModel.create(data)
             res.json({
                status:"ok",
                postedData
             })
        }
     });


   });

//error field in case something happens with multer
//   app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
//   console.log('This is the rejected field ->', error.field);
// });


 app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send("PAGE IS NOT FOUND");
})
```

Frontend code-

```
  import axios from "axios";
  import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

  const Form = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

   
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    // Append the file input to the form data
    const imageFile = formData.get("image");
    formData.append("image", imageFile);
  
    // Use Axios to send a POST request to your server with the form data
    axios
      .post("https://instabackend-gcwk.onrender.com/newpost", formData, {
        //.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/newpost", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      })
      .finally(navigate("/insta"));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>

      <button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}>Go Back Home</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

When i tried -

```
   app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
   console.log('This is the rejected field ->', error.field);
});
```

it's giving error field as "This is the rejected field -> image                                                                                                      "
Note: There is no issue in fetching the data

Comment: Can you add your frontend code?

Comment: @NeNaD added the frontend code

Comment: image uploading is working in postman but not via react

Comment: Hmmm... Can you try to `console.log(formData)` before sending it to the server. I am not sure what you did there, but maybe the `formData` is not send properly.

Comment: formData is as it should be with file details and its related method. The error in react is `AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500` which is the same server side multer error . see here for more details- [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-jang-bh3kkh?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: [github](https://github.com/nitishjha6519/instacloneAPI)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing append with set of `FormData()` is making the code work. [Javascript.info explains the working of formData() here](https://javascript.info/formdata)

```
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(event.target);

    //get image
    const imageFile = formData.get("image");
    //set image
    formData.set("image", imageFile);

    axios
      .post("https://instabackend-gcwk.onrender.com/newpost", formData, {
        
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="image">Image:</label>
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" accept="image/*" />

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```